# Matplotlib remove white space around patches

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the figure below (1) there is a lot of white space around the hexagonal grid that I cannot figure out how to remove. I've tried different methods i.e. `tight_layout` etc.

[image: SOM Hitmap]

The code is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import RegularPolygon
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy

def plot_som_hm(hm,colormap,a=1):
    # setup hexagon offsets
    m,n = hm.shape
    offsety = .75 * 2*a
    offsetx = numpy.sqrt(3) * a
    evenrow = numpy.sqrt(3)/2 * a

    # set up the figure
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2,2))
    ax.set_aspect('equal')

    # define colormap
    cmap = cm.ScalarMappable(None,colormap)
    norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=hm.min(),vmax=hm.max())

    # iterate over the hitmap, drawing a hexagon 
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            # calculate center point for current hexagonal grid & draw it
            offsetr = evenrow if i % 2 == 0 else 0
            x,y = (j*offsetx+offsetr,-i*offsety)
            hexg = RegularPolygon(
                (x,y),numVertices=6,radius=a,facecolor=cmap.cmap(norm(hm[i][j]))
            )
            ax.add_patch(hexg)
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(y)

    # add a scatter plot so all hexagons show up & turn off ticks
    ax.scatter(xs,ys,alpha=1.0)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])

    # add a colorbar
    sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=colormap,norm=norm)
    sm._A = []
    plt.colorbar(sm,ticks=range(int(hm.min()),int(hm.max())+1))

    # and show the hitmap
    plt.show()
```

which can be called by `plot_som_hm(hitmap,'inferno',-0.5)`

I am not sure if the whitespace is the result of calling subplots `(figsize=(2,2))` or something else. Being relatively new to `matplotlib` I am not sure where the whitespace is coming from i.e. if it is the figure, the axis or even the `plt` so searching on Google has not provided any relevant answers.

Comment: Which whitespace are you referring to? between the hexagons and the black border, or outside the black border?

Answer (score 1):

II suggest to read the x- and y-limits to see how you can adjust them to your needs, i.e.:

```
print(ax.get_xlim())
```

and then e.g.

```
ax.set_xlim(0.5, 5.5)
```

or whatever fits.

The same then with the y-axis.